# WP Query order WooCommerce products by total sales from date

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to return all products within WooCommerce ordered by their popularity (total sales) starting at a specific date.

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'products',
  'posts_per_page' => 2000,
  'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
  'meta_key'  => 'total_sales',
  'order' => 'desc',
  'date_query' => array(
      'column' => 'order_date',
      array(
        'after' => 'April 1st 2017',
      ),
  ),
);
$products =  new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $products->have_posts() ) {
  while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post();
    the_title();
    echo '<br>';
  endwhile;
}
```

This query returns all products ordered by popularity that have been added since `April 1st 2017`, not total product sales since `April 1st 2017`.

Comment: See my answer below, try to query for `shop_order` instead of `product`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `post_type` is wrong for what you want.

You're querying for `product` instead it should be `shop_order`:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'shop_order',
  'posts_per_page' => 2000,
  'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
  'meta_key'  => 'total_sales',
  'order' => 'desc',
  'date_query' => array(
      'column' => 'order_date',
      array(
        'after' => 'April 1st 2017',
      ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: I updated my post to include all the code, using the term `shop_order` returns no results.

Comment: Can we get an example of your `wp_posts` table data, wonder if it has total_sales in there for `shop_order` posts

Comment: I can confirm it does not have total sales in the database

Answer (score 0):

you can get best selling product between  specific date by using this query :

```
 $query_str = "SELECT order_item_meta_2.meta_value as product_id, SUM( order_item_meta.meta_value ) as line_total 
        FROM wpfi_woocommerce_order_items as order_items
        LEFT JOIN wpfi_woocommerce_order_itemmeta as order_item_meta ON order_items.order_item_id = order_item_meta.order_item_id
        LEFT JOIN wpfi_woocommerce_order_itemmeta as order_item_meta_2 ON order_items.order_item_id = order_item_meta_2.order_item_id
        LEFT JOIN wpfi_posts AS posts ON order_items.order_id = posts.ID
        WHERE posts.post_type = 'shop_order'
        AND posts.post_date BETWEEN '".$previous_date."' AND '".$current_date."'
        AND posts.post_status IN ( 'wc-completed') 
        AND order_items.order_item_type = 'line_item'
        AND order_item_meta.meta_key = '_line_total'
        AND order_item_meta_2.meta_key = '_product_id'
        GROUP BY order_item_meta_2.meta_value LIMIT 5";
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to use post_type=order.

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'shop_order',
  'posts_per_page' => 2000,
  'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
  'meta_key'  => 'order_total',
  'order' => 'desc',
  'date_query' => array(
      'column' => 'post_date',
      array(
        'after' => 'April 1st 2017',
      ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: The use of `order` as the `post_type` returns no results

Comment: Thanks for your updated answer this query too returns no results